# Is Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop is compatible with Acer Nitro 5 Acer Nitro 5 AN515-58-7272-CA / AN515-58-72CJ?

Tags: 14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, acer, debian, nitro

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I have purchased new Acer Nitro 5 AN515-58-7272-CA/AN515-58-72CJ. It has following configuration :
Intel i7-12700H
cache 24 MB
RAM 16 GB
SSD 512 GB
Right now it has windows But I want to use Ubuntu . I am little afraid about it's compatibility with ubuntu . I want to make sure about everything will work smooth after installing the Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop version on it .

Can you please let me know , Is that works with that laptop (with full compatibility) or not ?

What is best way to run Ubuntu on this laptop .

Thank you so much !!

Comment: You've tagged your question is about Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*which is EOL/EOSS & thus off-topic here*), but mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & WSL (*where 14.04 isn't supported*) so please check & correct your question details.

Comment: Yes it should be compatible

Comment: Do you mean [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] or dual-boot?  You have this tagged WSL, but you seem to be asking about compatibility for dual-boot for an Ubuntu Desktop install (WSL is Ubuntu Server).